# try except block in function

Tags: python, function, try-except

I get `KeyError` when running following code:

```
r={'foo':'bar'} #no timestamp
def function(f=None):
    try:
        print(f) # giving r['timestamp'] KeyError
    except:
        print("problem")
function(f=r['timestamp'])
```

But this is working, it prints `problem`:

```
try:
    print(r['timestamp']) # giving r['timestamp'] KeyError
except:
    print("problem")
```

I can't understand why try-except block is not working in function.

Comment: Cannot reproduce... https://repl.it/CrqG What is `r`?

Comment: working for me. What happens?

Comment: What is the variable `r`? Your problem might be caused by `r` being out of scope.

Comment: define `not working`

Comment: sorry r is added https://repl.it/CrqG/1 look at here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

function arguments are expressions that are evaluated before the value is passed to the function

so `r['timestamp']` executes before `function(f=...)` an so before any try block captures any exceptions

you can use [dict.get](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11041421/1176601) to avoid the `KeyError`:

```
function(f=r.get('timestamp', None))
```

or if you really need to capture the KeyError in the function:

```
def function(f=None):
    f = f or {}
    try:
        print(f['timestamp'])
    except KeyError:
        print("problem")
function(f=r)
```